# Use Contacts name in Gmail search

Tags: search, gmail, gmail-api, google-contacts-api

I would like to search from within Gmail (mail.google.com interface) all the emails from my friend Albert Baker. He has many email addresses such as  , ,  etc., so that I put them together under the Gmail Contacts with the Contact name of Albert Baker.

Gmail search syntax seems to provide a way to search NOT by the email address, but simply by the name, if the name is one word [1]. I have many friends called Albert, and several other Bakers. How do I do a search such as this:
`from:"Albert Baker"`

But the one above shows nothing.

Comment: That should work. Are you sure that you have him saved as a contact? Because if his email addresses does not contain his name, and you don't have him stored as a contact, it will not work.

Comment: Thank you! His gmail does not have his name, but rather more like this: albert.baker123@gmail.com. However, I have him as my Gmail contacts. I even tried renaming him in my contacts so that his name is AlbertBaker, just to make it a single word. But I still get zero search results.

Comment: Hmm, that's very annoying. Are you sure you are not logged into another account of yours that has never had contact with Albert? If not, this sound like a bug you should bring up with Google!

Comment: I am logging into my personal gmail account as well as my university email (which is, actually, provided by Gmail), but the two has very different contacts list.